# Custom header component be cropped after updating ag-grid to the latest version

Tags: components, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, custom-headers

Within an angular 9 app. I'm using the ag-grid and I decided to update it from `21.2.2` to        `24.0.0` version.

What I realized though is that it stopped render the custom header components properly.
For example I'm attaching two images that show how it looks like before and after.

**Before:**
[image]

**After:**
[image]

As you can see, after update the height of the header doesn't seem to follow the height of the custom components and as a result the plots are getting cropped.

Any ideas on what could cause this issue or what I can look for would be very helpful.

Comment: So after some research I found that I'm using the `[headerHeight]="(view === 'values') ? 100 : 250"` and although the view changes value the ag-grid seems not get the updated value of 250. Something has to do with the change detection probably.

Comment: Something you should check... There was a major redesign of ag-grid themes from version 22 to 23. This can affect layout. ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-themes-v23-migration